# How do I get all columns name from a directory and sudirectories ( including path and dataset name) in SAS

Tags: directory, path, sas, subdirectory

I need to list all columns names of all table  in a directory and subdirectories.

However, I tried to use the dictionary.columns but it doesn't show the datasets in the subdirectories

Here is the code

```
create table Kiwi.summarytablecolumns as select * from 
dictionary.columns where libname="Kiwi";
;
quit;
```

what I need is something like this:

Table Name |Columns Name |     Path                     |

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to do a recursive search to find all your libnames first and then create references for those and use the dictionary columns. Do you have x command enabled? recursive searches are pretty easy if you have it enabled. `options xcmd;`

Comment: Are the data sets in the sub-directory actively referenced by a `libnames` ?  How do you determine which is the 'parent` directory ? Is the parent actively referenced by a `libname` ?  If the parent **is** a libref, is that libname a path concatenation ?

Answer (score 3):

Modification from @Python R SAS solution,

1. Change from macro to full data step solution
2. Still query from dictionary table

/* Get a list of all subdirectories */

```
x "dir &basedirectory /s /b /o:n /ad > &basedirectory\list.txt";

filename dirs "&basedirectory\list.txt";

/* Parse each subdirectory into a macro variable */

data _null_;
   retain ii 0;
   infile dirs end=last;
   input;
   ii + 1;
   rc = libname(catt("DIR", put(ii,8. -l)), _infile_);
run;
```

Then your original query gets modified slightly:

```
proc sql;

create table Kiwi.summarytablecolumns as 
select * 
from dictionary.columns
where libname like 'DIR%';
;
quit;
```

Comment: The reason I resorted to a modified approach was that the path name of the dataset had to be part of this output dataset. Probably need some post processing to add that to this output.

Comment: Can be joined with dictionary.libnames based on libname to get folder path. In theory you could also use functions within data step to get all that information in a single pass but that’s an academic exercise.

Comment: A combination of 2/8 is likely the most robust solution that would work on any system. http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n0js70lrkxo6uvn1fl4a5aafnlgt.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Answer (score 2):

```
%let basedirectory = C:\users;

/* Get a list of all subdirectories */

x "dir &basedirectory /s /b /o:n /ad > &basedirectory\list.txt";

filename dirs "&basedirectory\list.txt";

/* Parse each subdirectory into a macro variable */

data _null_;
   retain ii 0;
   infile dirs end=last;
   input;
   call symput("dir" || strip(put(ii,8.)),_infile_);
   if last then call symput("dirnum", ii);
   ii + 1;
run;

/* Process each macro variable and get contents in corresponding library. Append results to grand summary dataset */

%macro loopthrough;

%do ii = 0 %to &dirnum;

  libname thislib "&&&dir&ii";

  proc contents data=thislib._all_ out=contents noprint;
  run;

  data contents;
    set contents;
    length path $200;
    where missing(typemem);
    TableName = memname;
    ColumnName = name;
    Path = "&&&dir&ii";
    keep TableName ColumnName Path;
  run;

  %if ii = 0 %then %do;
    data summary;
      set contents;
    run;
  %end;
  %else %do;
    proc append base=summary data=contents;
    run;
  %end;

%end;

%mend;

%loopthrough;
```

Comment: This assumes the OS is Windows and `XCMD` option is enabled.

Comment: FYI - there's a `libname` function, so you can assign all the lib names at once in the data step.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the script , but the loop for the libname thislib is not workiing, I got the message the libname thislib doesn't exist

Comment: Can you confirm that the list.txt file is populated and is being read correctly by the datastep when creating the macro variables?